# Populate html table with php multidimensional array

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, html-table

I'd like to put the data from a `MySQL` table in place `(HTML Table)`. Everything is dynamic. Product names **will not always be the same** (columns). The number of records **will not always be the same** (rows).

**MySQL Table (populate ROWS data)**

```
 iduser       idprod      quantity         date
  1234          65          60      2012-11-30 09:13:41.628
  1234          66          50      2012-11-30 09:13:41.628
  1234          64          80      2012-11-30 09:13:41.628
```

**MySQL Table (populate COLUMNS data)**

```
idprod  name                     date
66      Panettone de Truffas     2012-11-29 15:19:41
65      Panettone de Maracujá    2012-11-29 15:16:56
64      Panettone de Brigadeiro  2012-11-29 15:16:44
```

**Code**

```
    $panettones = array();
    $querySel = "SELECT * FROM registro_panettone";
    $resultSel = mysql_query($querySel);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($resultSel);
    $panettones = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++) {
        /*$panettones["id_user"] = mysql_result($resultSel,$i,0);
        $panettones["id_pan"] = mysql_result($resultSel,$i,1);
        $panettones["qtd"] = mysql_result($resultSel,$i,2);
        $panettones["data"] = mysql_result($resultSel,$i,3);*/
        $retorno = mysql_fetch_array($resultSel);
        $texto = "<tr>";
        $texto .= "<td>".$retorno[0]."</td>";
        $texto .= "<td>".$retorno[1]."</td>";
        $texto .= "<td>".$retorno[2]."</td></tr>";
        echo $texto;
}
```

Currently look like:

http://www.cacaushow.net.br/panettone_2012/rel.php

My wish is that it looks like:

http://www.cacaushow.net.br/panettone_2012/wish.php

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add the missing (empty) columns to your array generation, so your data columns match your header count.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to move to `PDO`. It will make your life easier long term, also take into account that `mysql_` commands are depricated. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: @dognose Maybe not works, the problem is about **reference**. Put the things in place. Put the data about code 65 in the 'td' with id = 65.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using html table (like you do in examples) you should always first check if the mysql field is empty. if it is replace it with & nbsp ; value. empty table cells (in some browsers) tend to show results like in your first example.

hope this was helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>;
```

wherever you have empty values instead of not doing anything there. And 
    <tr>
after each outer for loop

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Código</b></td>
        <td id='66'><b>Panettone de Truffas</b></td>
        <td id='65'><b>Panettone de Maracujá</b></td>
        <td id='64'><b>Panettone de Brigadeiro</b></td>
        <td><b>Data</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>2012-11-30 09:13:41.628</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>2012-11-30 09:13:41.628</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```